# How to add hatches on seaborn violin plot?

Tags: python, seaborn, violin-plot, hatchstyle

If I do something like:

```py
import seaborn as sns 
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")                                                                                                                                       
ax = sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
```

[image: Violin plot with 4 groups in different colors]

How can I change the colors by different hatches instead?
I tried the same way we do this for boxplot, but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as mpl
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
hatch = ['/','\\','+','o']
ihatch = iter(hatch)
ax = sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, color='g')
_ = [i.set_hatch(next(ihatch)) for i in ax.get_children() if isinstance(i, mpl.collections.PolyCollection)]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Any reason for the -1?

Comment: This is excellent, thank you @scott-boston!
I can't up or down vote, so it was not me. Sorry for that.